# Can't make Dovecot communicate with Postfix using SASL (warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: No such file or directory)

Tags: postfix, smtp, email, dovecot, debian-lenny

**Solved**. I will leave this as a reference to other people, as I have seen this error reported often enough on line.

I had to change the path

```
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
```

in my

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf
```

to relative, instead of absolute. This is because in Debian Postfix runs chrooted (and how does this affect the path structure?! Anyone?)

--

I am trying to get Dovecot to communicate with Postfix for SMTP support via SASL. the master plan is to be able to host multiple e-mail accounts on my (Debian Lenny 64 bits) server, using virtual users. Whenever I test my current configuration, by running

```
telnet server-IP smtp
```

I get the following error on mail.log

```
warning: SASL: Connect to /var/spool/postfix/private/auth failed: No such file or directory
```

Now, Dovecot is supposed to create the auth socket file, yet it doesn't. I have given the right privileges to the directory private, and even tried creating a auth file manually.

The output of

```
postconf -a
```

is

```
cyrus
dovecot
```

Am I correct in assuming from this that the package was compiled with SASL support?

My dovecot.conf also holds

```
      client {
        path = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
        mode = 0660
        user = postfix
        group = postfix
      }
```

I have tried every solution out there, and am pretty much desperate after a full day of struggling with the issue. Can anybody help me, pretty please?

Comment: The chroot mean that the whole chrooted system, /etc/, /dev/, and so on are under a specific directory.. as discussed here: https://wiki.debian.org/chroot

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use sasl within postfix you also have to say which type it has to use. The output of `postdonf -a` gives you the possible types. In your case you have to declare the following:

```
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
```